# How to get group_concat() like output from oracle so that I can get a comma separated list from a sigle column for each group by row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck in situation where I need a comma separated list from group by result sets. Let me give you a typical schema :

```
        username | lotno | img
        ------------------------
        a        | 0001  | 1.jpg
        ------------------------
        a        | 0001  | 2.jpg
        ------------------------
        a        | 0002  | 1.jpg
        ------------------------
        a        | 0002  | 2.jpg
        ------------------------
        a        | 0002  | 3.jpg
        ------------------------
        b        | 0003  | 1.jpg
        ------------------------
```

Now I want a group by result set like this :

```
    <pre>

    username | lotno       | count
    ------------------------------
    a        | 0001, 0002  | 5
    ------------------------------
    a        | 0001        | 1
    ------------------------------

    </pre>
```

How can I achieve this without writing a function or programming ? Can I do this using a query in Oracle.
Do not mind, the table structure shown is drawn using  tag. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  What does "without programming" mean to you?

Comment: without programming means, I could use Programming language like Java or others which will use the simple group by result set and output into what I required.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `count` field the number of lines per `username` and `lotno` (this is not clear from your example) ? If so, this could be:

```
select username, listagg(lotno, ', ') within group (order by lotno), nb
from
(
  select username, lotno, count(*) nb
  from your_table
  group by username, lotno
)
group by username, nb;
```

You can use the listagg clause from 11gR2.